# Как добавить поиск слова из сообщения целиком в бота на telebot Python

Tags: telegram, бот, поиск, txt

Мне нужно, чтобы бот искал слово в файле .txt целиком, а не только его части. Файл с городами, в которых есть представители нашего бренда, и при вводе пользователем города всё работает, но если он вводит, допустим, только "Мос", "Са", "Пе", бот также выдаёт позьзователю, что в его городе есть представители бренда. Как это исправить? Нигде не нашёл информацию, уже несколько способов испробовал.

````
СПОСОБ 1

@bot.message_handler()
def is_valid_city(message):
    citi = message.text
    a = open(r'A:\Python files\cities.txt.txt', encoding='utf-8')
    b = a.read()
    if citi in b:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В вашем городе есть представители нашего бренда.')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'К сожалению, не удалось распознать ваше сообщение. Пожалуйста, повторите попытку, используя команду /start')```

СПОСОБ 2

@bot.message_handler()
def search_str(message):
    a = message.text
    with open(r'A:\Python files\cities.txt.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        content = file.read()
        if a in content:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В вашем городе есть представители нашего бренда.')
        else:
            bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'К сожалению, не удалось распознать ваше сообщение. Пожалуйста, повторите попытку, используя команду /start')```
````

Comment: В таком случае может не стоит использовать в `if citi in b:` и `if a in content:` конструкцию `in`? Составьте список городов из файла, аля `['Самара','Москва',...]` и проверяйте по нему

Comment: это громоздко и неэффективно, хотелось бы сделать именно поиск по файлу. Но если других вариантов нет, не могли бы показать кусок кода с поиском по этому списку? не совсем понял, как это реализовать

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно банально составить список из текстового документа используя тройку строчек кода:

```
with open('cities.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
cities = [line.strip() for line in lines]

print(cities)
```

В моём случае cities.txt:

```
Москва
Самара
Санкт-Петербург
```

Вывод в терминале:

```
['Москва', 'Самара', 'Санкт-Петербург']
```

Далее уже можно проверить `a`, где в вашем случае `message.text` на `in`:

```
a = 'Москва'

if a in cities:
    print('ура')

a = 'Тольятти'

if a in cities:
    print('не ура')
```

Вывод:

```
ура
```

Answer (score 0):

Огромное спасибо пользователю Acinit! Всё получилось!

````
@bot.message_handler()
def search_str(message):
    a = message.text
    with open(r'A:\Python files\cities.txt.txt', 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
        lines = file.readlines()
    content = [line.strip() for line in lines]
    if a in content:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'В вашем городе есть представители нашего бренда.')
    else:
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id,
                         'К сожалению, не удалось распознать ваше сообщение. Пожалуйста, повторите попытку, используя команду /start')```
````